# How to write few bytes to a file in NAND without continuously trashing pages?

Tags: c

I have a persistent dictionary (string -> string map) that I write to a NAND filesystem as a log file. My binary format is:

```
1 byte - key size
<key size> bytes - key without the terminating nul-character
2 bytes - value size and flags
<value size> bytes - value without terminating nul-character
```

Usually, I write between 20 to 100 bytes with each change in the dictionary. But since this is been persisted on NAND this design causes a new page to be allocated each time, reducing my available NAND space by 2k on each iteration.

I can't cache the writes because I can't lose this data. It's running point of sales terminals, saving transaction data. My algorithm effectively writes and call flush, so this doesn't happen.

Now, is there a de-facto or standard algorithm to solve this problem? I've looked at power-down triggers on the target platform, but the SDK suggests using the NAND as the persistent layer.

Comment: Power-down triggers may not trigger if the power goes out abruptly, so you can't rely on any such thing.

Comment: Yeah, some old terminals also had capacitors just for this, but they are not reliable nowadays, after many years on the streets.

Comment: Not also, even: "... some old terminals even had capacitors..."

Comment: Can you mention what the target platform is? Your options would be radically different depending on what operating system (WinCE?, Linux?, VXWorks?, QNX? etc.) you have on the board.

Comment: We have to support 8 platforms, with lots of different terminal models. We support terminals from VeriFone, Sagem, Ingenico, Hypercom, PAX, Perto, Intellect and Windows (a virtual terminal developed in-house).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the NAND FLASH is limited to page-granularity on writes, I'm out of luck.
I could rely on some external persistent device, or on-shutdown routines, but I don't have access to any other secondary memory and old point of sale terminals even have capacitors for last resort routines, but they aren't reliable enough for transaction data.

I'll have to live with the FLASH limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... Just keep track of where in the page you are, and before writing, read in the last page, append your new data in memory, and write the same page back.

If the new data broke the page limit, start on a new page. This will happen if the new data doesn't fit in the remaining space for the last page written. When done, update the information about where the last write happened.

You say that your appends "cause a new page to be allocated each time", I'm not sure why that would be the case if you're appending to a byte sequence.

Of course, this requires page-level access to the memory. If all you have is file-level (like C's `FILE *` functions) access, you can't do this unless you know that your file layer is somewhat clever.

Comment: Explaining what "broke the page" means would be in order. Otherwise the answer is really confusing.

Comment: @JanHudec Thanks, I think I forgot some words there or something. Hopefully clearer now ...

Comment: I just have a buffered file API. The page size is 2k, but the internal buffer is limited to 512 bytes (according to the documentation). Anyways, I need to flush data immediately after every write, so I call the flush function after every write in this scenario.

@unwind: are you telling me to keep a page boundary, and before every write to disk, write to a internal buffer and seek to this stored page boundary, so I ALWAYS write a whole page? Are you telling me that the underlying layer will recognize that the overwritten part is the same, and thus it won't trash the current page?

Comment: @Spidey: If you only have a buffered file API, than you can't control what the flash does. In that case, the underlying layer either does what unwind describes, or you are out of luck. If it does not, your only chance is to coordinate with the operating system vendor.

Comment: I guess I am out of luck in this case. We planned the dictionary as persisting in a NOR FLASH, but we have a NAND FLASH, with page write granularity.